# What is the best way to minimize the punctuation in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, word-order

My own preference is for the first version below but I feel I tend to over-punctuate, so I welcome your opinions on this issue.

This is the house, which - when it was finished - was red, that Jack built.

This is the house that Jack built, which - when it was finished - was red.

This is the house that Jack built which when finished was red.

Comment: What color is it now? What’s with the little dashes? Are those commas?

Comment: Why do you want it all in one sentence? And what's wrong with _This is the house that Jack built, which was red when it was finished_? You don't have to delete everything, you know.

Comment: @tchrist. The dashes are intended to be em dashes, a commonly used punctuation mark. The colour is nugatory.

Comment: ThisistheredhousethatJackbuilt

Comment: @JohnLawler Agreed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All three sound possible but the first, because of the delayed "that" clause has a somewhat chaotic feel. An essential point, though, is that the first two are not equivalent to the third, that being so because of the lack of a comma after "built" in that third one; this particularity in the third formulation makes its "which" clause a *defining relative clause* (also called a restrictive clause and a descriptive clause), which the first two aren't (non restrictive clauses). Therefore, this minimizing approach is not valid in the third sentence (supposing that the non restrictive option is the one chosen). ([English grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining))

Comment: Thank you. I take your points. It is easier to absorb the thrust of an argument when it is directed at one’s own prose than when one is a mere bystander to others’ discussions.